# Text positioning inside table cell

Tags: tables, positioning, text, cell

My constructed table results in the following:

[image]

However, I want to place the checkmark and cross symbols vertically centered. How do I do it? Here is my code:

```
\begin{tabular}
   {|p{1.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline                                      
   Anonym & Precision degradation, Random shift, Black
   marker, Prefix preserving, Truncation  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \times & \times & \times\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Use m type columns instead of p type columns to verticaly center the contents.

Answer (score 1):

This way?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,amssymb, amstext}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % math-mode version of "c" column type

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
{|p{1.5cm}|m{3.5cm}|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
   \hline                                      
Anonym & Precision degradation, Random shift, Black
marker, Prefix preserving, Truncation  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \times & \times & \times\\ \hline

 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular with math column an m-column]